# Evaluate an idea of generating noise based on standard deviation

Tags: statistics, data-science, noise

I generate synthetic dataset using this method:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def generate_dataset(size, dim):

    dataset = [random.randint(0, 2 ** dim) for _ in range(size)]

    # Removes duplicates
    dataset = list(set(dataset))

    return dataset
```

As you can see, the data points are generated randomly from `[0 - 2^dim]`. For any dataset generated by this method, I want to add **noise** to it. Now, I am thinking of a simple way to do so but I am not sure if it is logically correct, so here it is:

1. Find the standard deviation of data points from the generated dataset.
2. Generate new data points that are NOT within this standard deviation.
3. Add them to your original dataset, and shuffle.

Is this way of generating noise sound?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are creating outliers. noise to me is more like adding a small number(+/- number) to the data points. for example, how many steps did you walk today? it could be 100, but some tracing device might read 95 or 110. that difference is noise.

not sure if this helps.